# How can I return a response to an AWS lambda function for a longer running process before lambda times out?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a s3 bucket trigger set up to call a lambda function when a new file is saved to the bucket. That lambda function then parses the event data and sends it as a post request to an api running on on ec2 instance.  That post request, when received starts a file conversion pipeline process that can take a minute or so to run.  The lambda seems to time-out every 3 seconds, so it keeps trying and then saying 'timed out' because it never receives a response from the api call.  The actual conversion process kicks off and completes just fine though so thats not an issue but I didn't think this was good practice. Is there a fix to this or some other way I should be configuring this?

My lambda function is

```
import json
import requests

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Get the bucket name and object key from the event
    bucket_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    object_key = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']

    # Encode the data as JSON
    data = {
        'bucket_name': bucket_name,
        'object_key': object_key
    }
    json_data = json.dumps(data)

    # Make the POST request
    url = "http://<domain>/api/new/file"
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=json_data)
    
    # Return the response status code
    print(f'response code: {response}')
    # return response.status_code
    print(data)
    return data
```

The api on the ec2 instance is:

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/api/new/file', methods=['POST'])
def handle_request():
    
    content_type = request.headers.get('Content-Type')
    if (content_type == 'application/json'):
        data = request.json
        file_name = os.path.basename(data['object_key'])
    
        try:
            <my_long_function>(file_name)
        except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                return "False"
        return "True"
    else:
        return 'Content-Type not supported!'
```

Comment: if the workload requires more than 15 mins to complete lambda is not the ideal choice, ice ec2 instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because lambda by default runs for 3 secs. All you have to do is increase the timeout value, which can be up to 15 mins == 900 secs
Lambda > Configuration > General Configuration > Timeout